# Update Global Variable With One of Multiple Onclicks

Tags: javascript

I have three divs, each with an onclick (*a*, *b*, and *c*). I want each to send a unique value back to a global variable *x* (e.g. *a* makes *x* = 1, *b* makes *x* = 2, etc.). I had some modest success at once point, but now it looks like the code is just running top to bottom, ignoring the other functions and simply making *x* equal to the last function's updated value, *c*.

HTML:

```
<div id='testChoice'>Choose action</div>
<div id='a'>a</div>
<div id='b'>b</div>
<div id='c'>c</div>
```

JS:

```
var x = "";

function aChoice() {
  this.x = "a";
}

function bChoice() {
  x = "b";
}

function cChoice() {
  x = "c";
}

document.getElementById("a").onclick = aChoice();
document.getElementById("b").onclick = bChoice();
document.getElementById("c").onclick = cChoice();

document.getElementById("testChoice").innerHTML = x;
```

Variable *x* (it is only being displayed in the HTML for testing) is what I want to update. It will be changed to an int value for use in other functions. The idea is that the user's selection will update the variable which is then passed to other functions. Right now, *x* always comes out as *c*, and no onclicks are recognized.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: That last line is not going to magically run when x updates.... and you are calling those methods....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're repeating a lot of code. This would be a simpler way to achieve what you're trying.

```js
var x = "";

function choice(value) {
  x = value;
  document.getElementById("testChoice").innerHTML = value;
}

document.getElementById("a").onclick = choice.bind(null, "a")
document.getElementById("b").onclick = choice.bind(null, "b")
document.getElementById("c").onclick = choice.bind(null, "c")
```

```html
<div id='testChoice'>Choose action</div>
<div id='a'>a</div>
<div id='b'>b</div>
<div id='c'>c</div>
```

Also, your current code always shows `c` because your last line is executed only once. And the last time `x` is assigned a value is when you say `cChoice()`.

Answer (score 0):

This wold help you.For `OnClick` you should provide function name only. `aChoice()` will actually invoke at the time of adding `onclick` listener. You were getting last function output because cChoice is last function executed in order.

```js
var x = "";

function aChoice() {
  x = "a";
  document.getElementById("testChoice").innerHTML = x;
}

function bChoice() {
  x = "b";
  document.getElementById("testChoice").innerHTML = x;
}

function cChoice() {
  x = "c";
  document.getElementById("testChoice").innerHTML = x;
}

document.getElementById("a").onclick = aChoice;
document.getElementById("b").onclick = bChoice;
document.getElementById("c").onclick = cChoice;
```

```html
<div id='testChoice'>Choose action</div>
<div id='a'>a</div>
<div id='b'>b</div>
<div id='c'>c</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

With the `let` or with the closure of the way can be a very good solution

```js
 var test = document.querySelectorAll(".test");
 for (let i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
  test[i].onclick = function () {
   document.getElementById("testChoice").innerHTML = test[i].innerHTML;
  }
 }
```

```html
<div id='testChoice'>Choose action</div>
<div class="test">a</div>
<div class="test">b</div>
<div class="test">c</div>
```